# How do I properly rebase a git's branch into another?

Tags: git

I have 2 branches in Git, namely master and dev .

I'd like to convert dev branch's content into master, that is to say I wanna ditch the state of dev, and change it to how it is like in master, how can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resetting the state of one branch to be exactly the same as another - including the commit history - is known as a `reset` in git, not a rebase. This is performed with the reset command.

```
git checkout dev
git reset --hard master
```

If dev is a published branch, then you probably want to retain the commit history. The most logical thing to do is to merge `master` in to `dev` and then reset the tree to match `master`'s.

E.g.

```
git checkout dev
git merge master

# ... resolve any conflicts and commit if needed.

# Reset the tree to master
git reset --hard master

# Reset just the branch pointer to the merge
git reset --soft HEAD@{1}

# Commit a 'revert' of the differences to dev
git commit -m "Revert unneeded dev changes"
```

This will make sure that you won't need to wind back history which is important if people are tracking the dev branch.